# Subsetting in R with multiple observations per person

Tags: r, subset

I have a data set, a small part of which is

```
     ID time GLUCOSE
1    NA    6      NA
2  1302    0      78
3  1302    6      90
4  1927    0      NA
5  1927    6      NA
6  2121    0      94
7  2121    3      90
8  2121    6     100
9  2121    9      93
10 2121   12      88
11 4022    0      87
12 4022    6      94
13 4022   12      87
14 4867    0     102
15 4867    3     100
16 4867    6     103
17 4867    9      99
18 4867   12     106
19 5351    0     108
20 5351    3     112
```

I would like to retain only those people whose value of glucose at time 0 is above 100, but I would like to keep all the values for those people. Thus, for ID = 4867 I would like all 5 values retained, even those under 100, since his value at time 0 was 102.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd first get the relevant IDs and then subset on these IDs like so:

```
ids <- df$ID[ which( df$time==0 & df$GLUCOSE > 100 ) ]
ids
# [1] 4867 5351

#  We can then subset the dataframe using these IDs and the %in% operator
df[df$ID %in% ids , ]
#    ID time GLUCOSE
#14 4867    0     102
#15 4867    3     100
#16 4867    6     103
#17 4867    9      99
#18 4867   12     106
#19 5351    0     108
#20 5351    3     112
```